# Mysql 5.6 with AWS Opsworks Mysql Layer?

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, aws-opsworks

I am looking for someone that might know how to override the default install of MySql 5.5 on the Opsworks MySql layer.

I have tried enabling the ius repo and then a custom recipe to install the mysql56u-server, mysql56u-common packages, however all attempts thus far have failed due to the fact that mysql is being installed way earlier in the setup process.

I have not located the actual recipe that is selecting the packages for mysql55.

Anyone have any insight on this?

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: I figured this out, with just overriding the default mysql cookbook with a custom cookbook, mysql::server recipe, modified it to use ius repos, updated the package names based on the ius repo and it works!

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the [mysql Cookbook provided by AWS](https://github.com/aws/opsworks-cookbooks/tree/release-chef-11.10/mysql), the recipe that installs the client (recipes/client_install.rb) includes the following:

```
case node[:platform]
  when "redhat", "centos", "fedora", "amazon"
    package mysql_name
  else "ubuntu"
    package "mysql-client"
end
```

The mysql_name variable is set earlier in the recipe:

```
mysql_name = node[:mysql][:name] || "mysql"
```

Looking at the attributes file (attributes/server.rb), the default values are set according to the Host's OS:

```
if rhel7?
  default[:mysql][:name] = "mysql55-mysql"
else
  default[:mysql][:name] = "mysql"
end
```

You can overwrite the name value to suit your needs:

```
default[:mysql][:name] = "mysql56u"
```

This can be achieved by provisioning your own [customize attributes file](https://github.com/aws/opsworks-cookbooks/blob/release-chef-11.10/mysql/attributes/customize.rb) in your Custom Cookbooks, or simply utilize the following Custom JSON in your Stack settings:

```
{
  "mysql": {
    "name": "mysql56u"
  }
}
```